# PMP experience requirement

Tags: pmp

PMP experience requirement-I'm scrounging for hours!
1. On a parenting leave of absence from the workforce I started up a small business, went on training courses, incorporated the business, ran it for a few years and then closed the business to return to the full time workforce. Would this count as "leading and directing"? Being self-employed at the time, could I vouch for myself if audited?
2. I did a project management course- the whole course was on writing a project proposal (which I did). Would this count as "leading and directing?"
Thanks!

Comment: I believe the class would go toward your formal education requirements. As for the "leading and directing" requirement it appears that you have done both over the time as an independent. You would likely be able to convince an auditor that the work fit that description. It's not the IRS, they are just trying to be generally convinced that you are part of the profession. Good luck. - Poymath, PMP & PMI-ACP

Comment: The only person who can answer this is PMI; the only possible response you'll get here are opinions.

Answer (score 1):

You can add your small business experience as credentials to apply for the PMP. The important thing is to list the projects you have had done through that time and how did you approach each project. it is important to explain how you initiated, planned, monitored & controlled, and closed that project. try to read about these process so you know how to document your projects for the application.
Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

You need to have 4500 hours of PM experience in a leading & directing role to to do PMP. So, PM role is must before doing PMP. However, PM role is not equivalent to PM designation/title. PM role means that you should have managed full or part of a project. Your role in the project could be of vendor management, team management, client management etc. The projects could be related to any industry. They could be big or small, technical or non-technical etc.

So, some of your business experience can be counted as PM experience - only you can determine how much.

You can read more about the details of 4500 hours of experience here - 
(http://www.pmbypm.com/go/4500-hours-explanation-cornelius-ficthner/)